# Problem with RSelenium for dynamic list (loop not working)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to take this website https://www.almg.gov.br/atividade-parlamentar/projetos-de-lei/texto/?tipo=PL&num=173&ano=2023, and scrap the description of witch law, the thing is that description is at the links on that list. I'm trying to use Rselenium, but I can open witch link on the list, but he is only taking the first or the last description.

Here's the code i use:

```r
`#Puxando os Pacotes
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(netstat)
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#Inicializando o Selenium 
remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                          verbose = FALSE,
                          port = free_port(), chromever = NULL)

remDr <- remote_driver$client
remDr$open()
link <-remDr$navigate(
  'https://www.almg.gov.br/atividade-parlamentar/projetos-de-lei/texto/?tipo=PL&num=173&ano=2023')

#IDENTIFICAÇÕES

identificação <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", 
    ".js_interpretarLinksREADY") 
numero_data <-lapply(identificação, function(x) {
  x$getElementText() %>% unlist()  
  }) %>% flatten_chr()

identificação2 <-remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", 
    "/html/body/main/div[4]/div/span/p[4]/a")
link_lei <- lapply(identificação, function(x) {
  x$getElementAttribute('href') %>% unlist()
  }) %>% flatten_chr()


#ABRINDO UMA LEI 
remDr$navigate("https://www.almg.gov.br/legislacao-mineira/LEI/102/1947/")
ementa <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "/html/body/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]")$getElementText() %>%
  unlist()

#RETORNANDO À PAGINA PRINCIPAL
remDr$navigate(
  'https://www.almg.gov.br/atividade-parlamentar/projetos-de-lei/texto/?tipo=PL&num=173&ano=2023')

#PARA CAPTAR AS DESCRIÇÕES

for (t_url in link_lei [1:3]) {
  remDr$navigate(t_url)
  descrição <- ementa
  remDr$navigate(
  'https://www.almg.gov.br/atividade-parlamentar/projetos-de-lei/texto/?tipo=PL&num=173&ano=2023')
  Sys.sleep( 1 )
}`
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting question! Could you clarify what exactly on the webpage your are trying to get? A list of links? the text from the webpage that each link leads to?